# jQuery & Handling Element ID's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
    function mandatoryField(manF)
    {
        var fieldId = $(manF).val();
        if(fieldId == "")
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

It doesn't work, but this does:

```
    function mandatoryField()
    {
        var fieldId = $("#element_1").val();
        if(fieldId == "")
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Presume, on my first example, mandatoryField is called as such:

```
  mandatoryField("#element_1")
```

Why doesn't it work when I try to replace the absolute element ID name with a variable?

**Edit:**

Most recent code - non-working:

```
    function isAmExSelected()
    {
         return $("#creditCardType").val() == "American Express";
    }

    function containsOnlyDigits(str)
    {
         return str.match(/[^0-9]/) == null;
    } 

    function validateCCNumber()
    {
         var ccn = $("#creditCardNumber").val();
         var onlyDigits = containsOnlyDigits(ccn);
         if(isAmExSelected())
         {
             return ccn.length == 15 && onlyDigits;
         }
         else
         {
             return ccn.length == 16 && onlyDigits;
         }
    }

    function mandatoryField(manF) 
    {
        var fieldId = $("#" + manF).val();
        return fieldId != "";
    }


    function registerValidation(id, validateMethod(), errorMethod)
    {
          $(id).change(function(){
              if(validateMethod() == false)
              {
                  errorMethod();
              }
          });
    }


    $(document).ready(function(){
        registerValidation("#creditCardNumber", validateCCNumber, function(){alert("Invalid Credit Card Number!")});
        $('input[type=text][class=mandatory]').blur(function(){
            if (mandatoryField(this.id)) {
                     alert('Field:' + this.id + ' is mandatory!')
            }
        });
    });
```

**Edit 2**

I've rewritten the entire thing to look like this:

```
        $('input[type=text][class=mandatory]').blur(function(){
            if (!($("#" + this.id).val().length)) {
                     alert('Field:' + this.id + ' is mandatory!');
            }
        });
```

If a text input of the mandatory class blurs, then run the function: if #foo.val() does not have length (i.e. has no text in it), run the alert. I believe it should work, but it does not.

Comment: Maybe you could create a http://jsfiddle.net/ for your example.

Comment: you dont need mandatory pass mandatory field name

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
    function mandatoryField(manF)
    {
        if($('#' + manF).val() == "")
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
mandatoryField("element_1");
```

But this will get you value of element, not it's id. I'm not sure what you are tring to accomplish.

Trigger on field blur option:

```
$('input[type=text][class=classForMandatoryFields]').blur(function(){
 if (mandatoryField(this.id)) {
   alert('Field:' + this.id + ' is mandatory!')
 }
});
```

Comment: I'm testing if something has been typed into a input type=text element called #element_1.

Comment: I've edited my script, it should work. Try it and let me know. Additionally if you provide a bit more info we could make this process a bit easier and faster, for example checking it on form submit or on field leave event (blur). More information can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/blur/

Comment: Your newest edit still doesn't work, I've updated my question with my most recent code.

Comment: Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/hadvE/ your function does work there. Let me ask stupid question: have you included jQuery to your site? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Update your code to so:

```
function mandatoryField(manF)
{
    var fieldId = $("#" + manF).val();
    if(fieldId == "")
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and then try again.

Comment: This doesn't work for me in the same fashion I described in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Both pieces of code should work the same irrespective of whether the selector is passed in as an argument, or provided as a literal to `$` directly. Also, instead of the `if..else`, you could do

```
function mandatoryField(manF) {
    var fieldId = $(manF).val();
    return fieldId != "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay this will not work because jquery will assume manF is a DOM object but instead you are passing string.

have you ever tried

```
var tr = $('#element1') //----------1

alert($(tr).val()) //------------2
```

tr is actually a dom object

**UPDATE::**

why don't you try this one

```
//some code on some event

if(!check_mandatory())
//do something else

else do another thing

//some code on some event
```

and the function

```
function check_mandatory()
{
    $('.mandatory').each(function{
        if($(this).val() == ""){
            alert($(this).attr("name") + "required");
                            //or you can use id or any attrib
            return false;
        }
    })
}
```

**note** code might not work not tested, if it did not work then let me know

Comment: I thought that variables may be strings and still work? How should I remedy this problem?

Comment: @Andrei check jao answer or Marek'answer , sure that must work

Answer (score 0):

Could you try:

```
var fieldId = manF.val();

mandatoryField($("element_1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides your selector problem, you could rewrite your function like this:

```
function mandatoryField(manF){
    return $(manF).val().length;
}
```

This is, because in JavaScript everything has a truth or false meaning. For numbers, 0 is false.

**EDIT:**

My test works just fine:

```
function mandatoryField(manF){
    return $(manF).val().length;
}

(...)

<input id="test" value=""/>
<input type="button" value="dd" onClick="alert('length: ' + (mandatoryField('#test'))"/>
```